atomic resource counting in dynamodb
Referencing "Approach 2 – Optimistic concurrency control" - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implement-resource-counters-with-amazon-dynamodb/
I have a table where I keep track of a count in a nested field. I set the count to x, and launch a x jobs to process items. Each job decrements the count by 1. This is my UpdateItem call, where I verify that
current_count = get_current_count_from_db # READ the item via hash key and consistent read

expression_attribute_names = { '#some_id' => some_id, '#another_id' => another_id, '#count' => 'count' }

condition_expression = 'metadata.something.#some_id.#another_id.#count = :curr'

update_expression = 'SET metadata.something.#some_id.#another_id.#count = metadata.something.#some_id.#another_id.#count - :dec'

expression_attribute_values: { ':dec' => 1, ':curr' => current_count }

The above block is retried via exponential backoff a few times if I receive the conditional check failed exception, where I get the item again to get the new current count.
I also set return_values: 'UPDATED_NEW'.
However, I am sometimes encountering situations where my counter is not decremented to 0. I see in the logs 2 jobs decrementing the count from the same current count to the same new count. For example, I see 2 logs decrementing the counter from 5 to 4.
I have confirmed that the initial counter and the number of jobs are correct.
Any idea what I am not understanding? My goal is to set a count and launch a bunch of jobs to decrement the count to 0, accurately.
I also read Are DynamoDB Updates strongly consistent? and feel like my approach is correct.

The general issue with this approach is how do you handle a 500 error in the response (like a dropped network). You don't know if the network error happened before or after the mutation applied. By default the client will retry. If it sees the number lower, does that mean its earlier write succeeded? Maybe it was another thread that succeeded. So things aren't perfectly accurate. That's why the blog introduces transactions when perfect accuracy is required. You say here your logs show double decrements. Unlikely. But possibly client-side logging would show double attempts.

If the update call raises, the job retries a few more times. I don't care if the count goes less than 0, but I do care if it never gets to 0. In my logs I can find 2 different jobs logging the same thing after the update call, which surprised me. I'm not sure how I can use transaction here to ensure perfect accuracy when updating a single item, across different jobs, do you have an example?

Individual writes are always serialized. So there’s no way with pure decrements for the same decrement to happen twice. I’d look at places where your logging output could differ from actual internal database actions. Know what I mean?
